# KNPMenu custom order

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, knpmenu

Is there an easy way to order the sonata admin menu with a custom order?

This is my actual menu:

[image]

And for example I want the next order:

- Usuario
- Home
- Capacidades
- Presencia
- Calidad
- Noticias
- Etc...

Answer (score 3):

The order of the menu items is defined by your admin config file, under the entry `sonata_admin.dashboard.groups`. It's the same as the order of your items on the dashboard. [Here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/dashboard.html) is the doc

If you want to go further in customizing the menu, you can override the knp builder by making a menu listener, in which you'll be able to choose the order of your items too. It is well explained in the [Knp doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a response
https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu/

// src/EventListener/MenuBuilderListener.php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Event\ConfigureMenuEvent;

final class MenuBuilderListener
{
public function addMenuItems(ConfigureMenuEvent $event): void
{
$customWeeklyOrder = [
"Item that is seconds but i want first",
"Item that is first but i want second",
];

```
    $menu = $event->getMenu();

    $weeklyMenu = $menu->getChildren()['My group'];

    $weeklyChildren = $weeklyMenu->getChildren();

    usort($weeklyChildren, function ($a, $b) use ($customWeeklyOrder) {
        $aIndex = array_search($a->getName(), $customWeeklyOrder);
        $bIndex = array_search($b->getName(), $customWeeklyOrder);

        return $aIndex - $bIndex;
    });


    $weeklyMenu->setChildren($weeklyChildren);

    
}
```

}

## config/services.yaml

services:
app.menu_listener:
class: App\EventListener\MenuBuilderListener
tags:
- { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.configure.menu.sidebar, method: addMenuItems }